# preposition choice: at/in hand

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm wondering which preposition to use in the following. If both are acceptable, what is the difference?

> Our officers have to concentrate 100 per cent on the task **at**/**in** hand.
>
> Peter turned his attention to the task **at**/**in** hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*At hand* = nearby

*In hand* = being worked on at present

'The task at hand' would be a job that presented itself as obviously the next thing that needed doing. So it depends whether they are already working on the tasks or not.